# How to use jQuery-Autocomplete with a json returned object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use the jQuery-Autocomplete library on an text-input field ([documentation here](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)).
Therefor I use this Ajax lookup to get data from the db:

```
// terminal.js

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax("getStocksAvailable/", {
        method: "GET",
        async: "True",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var myDataInAutocompleteFormat = $.map(response, function (response) {
                return {value: response.fields.description, data: response.pk};
            });

            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                source: myDataInAutocompleteFormat,
                lookup: myDataInAutocompleteFormat,
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    alert("You selected: " + suggestion.value + ", " + suggestion.data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
```

which returns `response` as json in this format:

```
[0 … 99]
0:
 fields: {description: "DP WORLD"}
     description: "DP WORLD"
 model: "feeder.stocksavailablemodel"
 pk: 17969
__proto__: Object
1: {model: "feeder.stocksavailablemodel", pk: 17970, fields: {…}}
2: {model: "feeder.stocksavailablemodel", pk: 17971, fields: {…}}
```

I would like to have jQuery auto-completing the input-field using all of the `description` values in the json.

```
// html

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/terminal.js' %}"></script>
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at Object.success (terminal.js:30)
    at c (VM1560 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM1560 jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (VM1560 jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM1560 jquery.min.js:2)
```

I assume that the autocompleter doesn't like the format of the json. But I don't know how to make it fit its requirement so it is able to handle the data.

Json return as screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation autocomplete accepts data only in two formats, value-data or only value:

```
{
    // Query is not required as of version 1.2.5
    "query": "Unit",
    "suggestions": [
        { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
        { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
        { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
    ]
}

{
    "query": "Unit",
    "suggestions": ["United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States"]
}
```

Then you need to map your object to bring it in the required format. You can use the transformResult function to manage data from an Ajax call

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    paramName: 'searchString',
    transformResult: function(response) {
        return {
            suggestions: $.map(response.myData, function(dataItem) {
                return { value: dataItem.valueField, data: dataItem.dataField };
            })
        };
    }
});
```

Look at this example with local lookup (no ajax):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mbxtd8

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried to adapt accordingly and updated my question. Now it looks like autocomplete won't work properly, hm

Comment: @Phanti '.autocomplete is not a function' means that the reference to JQuery/JQuery UI/JQuery Autocomplete is missing or not well referenced, check index.html of my example.

Comment: this is weird rly, I literally copy/pasted your references, still it isn't recognized.

Comment: could you reproduce your code on stackblitz or similar? I will try to check it.

Comment: hey Luciano, it works! It seems my Django template inheritance got some issues... thank you!